# Is this sentence correct? 打扫大客厅这么多累的啊

Tags: grammar, mandarin

If not how would it be corrected using the exact same characters?

And what is the issue with the original sentence?

Struggling a bit with word order!

Comment: Is this an exercise that you are given several words to make a meaning sentence?

Comment: Restore a scramble sentence is a good exercise for identify different word types and their relation, but it is hard for beginners

Answer (score 1):

If the rule of the game is all characters must be used, I guess I can play it like this:

"**打扫这么大的客厅多累啊!**" (cleaning such a big living room, how tiring!)

> what is the issue with the original sentence?
>
> 打扫大客厅这么多累的啊

"打扫大客厅"(cleaning the main living room) is the topic, followed by the comment/opinion "多累啊"

'这么' and '的' are not needed

Comment: +1 If I were to use all provided characters to form a correct sentence, this would probably be it

Answer (score 0):

As you can't count 累 probably not good to use 这么多累。

打扫完一个大客厅，好累哦

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I have to use those exact characters to construct the sentence. Would <打扫大客厅的多这么累阿> work?

Answer (score 0):

Few variations:

1. 这么(样)打扫大客厅多累啊! // Cleaning a big living room in this way tires (me)
   out.
2. 打扫大客厅多累啊! //  Cleaning a big living room tires (me) out.
3. 打扫大客厅这么累啊! //  Cleaning a big living room tires (me) out.

The issue with your original one 打扫大客厅这么多累的啊 is that you put two modifiers 这么 and 多 for 累，so you might have to remove one. And also 的 is misused and should be removed.

Also, 这么多（的） + noun is the correct structure, like 这么多（的）爱，这么多（的）人. However, 这么多（的) can not modify an adjective, so 这么多（的）累 is a wrong expression.